# What will be the next consideration if the ORDER BY field is NULL

Tags: soql

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM MyObj__c ORDER BY field2
```

Say all your `field2` have `NULL`. Is there any default next consideration to order the result list? May be the order of selected fields or something like that?

To the point, can you confirm that the result list will be in the same order every time you perform the query, even the `field2` is `NULL`? Looks like it's not.

Comment: I would suggest to make wrapper and custom sorting  -- that what I did in this scenario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always write a query like:

```
[SELECT id, field1, field2, NullField3 
  FROM Big_Object
  Order By NullField3, field2, field1 NULLS LAST
  LIMIT 100 ];
```

1. You provide list of order by fields separated by comma.
2. You can command position of null if there are null values. You can write `NULLS FIRST` or 'NULLS LAST' after order by field.

More Complex:

```
[SELECT id, field1, field2, NullField3 
      FROM Big_Object
      Order By NullField3, 
               field2 DESC NULLS FIRST, 
               field1 ASC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT 100 ];
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [these docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm):

> There is no guarantee of the order of results unless you use an ORDER BY clause in a query

You could, however, add a second field in the `ORDER BY` in a query to order by a second field. For instance, a query such as:

```
[SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact ORDER BY FirstName, LastName]
```

Might yield something like:

> FiN | LaN
>
> ========
>
> Dan | Bar
>
> Dan | Foo
>
> Dan | Smith
>
> Rob | Jones
>
> Rob | West

Notice how it orders by FirstName first, but then will order by the LastName. **This would at least give you some control as to what is ordered next should a certain column be null.** The only other consideration you could dwell on here would be whether or not you use `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST` if a column has a mix of null and non-null values.

For instance:

```
[SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contact ORDER BY FirstName NULLS LAST, LastName]
```

Otherwise, as the docs state, there's no way to guarantee any order because if all of a column is null, there's nothing to order by except null itself.

Hopefully, this goes some way to answering your question.